# react useRef not getting assigned

Tags: reactjs

So i'm trying to create a ref using the indexes of 'todos' prop but for some reason useRef doesn't work with it, what am i doing wrong?

here's the example

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'

function Todos({todos}) {
   /* todos prop is an array of objects */

   /* FYI todos.map((_, index) => index) returns [0, 1, 2]*/

  /* CASE 1 */
  const order = useRef(todos.map((_, index) => index))
  console.log(order) /* returns {current: []} */

  /* CASE 2 */
  const order = useRef([0, 1, 2])
  console.log(order) /* returns {current: [0,1,2]} */
}
```

Comment: You might wanna see this post for this issue of dynamic ref    https://medium.com/@jalexmayer/react-refs-with-dynamic-names-d2262ab0a0b0

Comment: Almost certainly the todos prop is empty when the component is first mounted. You'll have to show a [mcve] because the code you've now shown works if you pass an array of objects to the component: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-butterfly-gv5ot

Comment: Thanks, i found a working solution. the todos prop id passed from the parents state. i found out that useRef captures the prop initially when it's empty

Answer (score -2):

I found a working solution. for some reason setting the current property of the order seems to work

```
 const order = useRef();
 order.current = todos.map((_, index) => index)) /* works!!!*/
```

Comment: It works because `todos` will update on the next render, on initial render its an empty array.

Comment: What's the point of using a ref when you're just always using the prop anyway?

Comment: i didn't post the rest of the code bro. it's part of a greater logic. thanks for asking